# Dynamodb - Cloudformation specifying KMS Key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

Trying to create a DynamoDB table with a specific KMS key instead of using the AWS Managed Service Key but can't find how to do this.

The documentation provides an example of using the managed key: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/encryption.tutorial.html

Does anyone know how to specify a CMK Key for Encryption at Rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now possible via the `KMSMasterKeyId` property.

```
{
  "KMSMasterKeyId" : String,
  "SSEEnabled" : Boolean,
  "SSEType" : String
}
```

> The KMS customer master key (CMK) that should be used for the AWS KMS encryption. To specify a CMK, use its key ID, Amazon Resource Name (ARN), alias name, or alias ARN. Note that you should only provide this parameter if the key is different from the default DynamoDB customer master key alias/aws/dynamodb.